# What is the maximum size for azure websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am porting my asp web to new azure website. My site has huge static content so is there a size limit for azure website i should worry about now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Azure websites are stored on a content share which is accessible from all the the "web servers" in the farm.

I just collected the information, that during this preview, every subscription has a maximum of 1GB of storage in content share which subscription users can divide into 10 websites.

Depending on your requirement, you can consume the entire 1GB for 1 website or you can distribute it among the other 10 (or fewer) websites. However you cannot exceed the 1GB size limit and total 10 websites.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of Azure IIS restrictions?

Comment: During Preview i may not be possible to provide a list as things may change as time goes by..

Comment: From one of you other answers I now get that Windows Azure Web Sites are different from Web Server Role.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion as the correct word is "Windows Azure Websites". May I ask for the link where you found "Web Sites"?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I know the answer to max size, but... when talking about static content, one thing you can do is store that static content in blob storage, rather than in the Web Site. I realize this adds a cost to your site, but... at about $0.12 / GB / month (or $0.09 if you go with local replication only), it's rather inexpensive to store a whole bunch of static content. Also, this means static content is served out of blob storage instead of through Web Sites (and IIS), probably resulting in better performance for your site. You'd just need to modify your URL links (for public content) to point to url's in blob storage.

Oh, and should you decide this is a good path for you to take, you could go one more step and enable CDN for your storage account.